# How to make keyboard event using javascript without keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

As My question I want to press F11 with help of javascript so My test can be opened in new window with fullscreen.
Help me soon. it would be good if any jsfiddle is there

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as it violates a browser's sandbox capabilities.

However, there are workarounds such as - http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/fullscreen/